# Did the sci-fi glam rock era inspire any direct novel or short story spinoffs?

Tags: music

There was a lot of great sci-fi inspired rock coming out in the late 70s and early 80s from Bowie (Major Tom, Ziggy Stardust, etc), Styx (Mr Roboto, Come Sale Away), Pink Floyd (Interstellar Overdrive), and on and on.  Was any fiction writing done about these characters and scenarios?  Major Tom novel?  etc...

Comment: Sort of: [Kiss Meets the Phantom of the Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiss_Meets_the_Phantom_of_the_Park)

Comment: Questions asking for lists of works, or recommendations, are off-topic.

Comment: I didn't ask for a list :) just asked a yes or no question

Answer (score 8):

[The Time of the Hawklords](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?861548) by Michael Moorcock features the band Hawkwind (or members thereof) as did the sequel Queens of Deleria. I have read neither, but my contacts tell me that both are enjoyable tosh rather than great literature.

Comment: "Enjoyable tosh" is possibly giving it more credit that it deserves. It's far, far below Moorcock's normal standard, and, as the page you've linked to shows, it's debatable as to how much of it he actually wrote (if any) with the rest being supplied by Michael Butterworth.

Comment: No way would Hawkwind count as glam rock. IMO

Comment: @DannyMcG well neither would Pink Floyd and the question mentions them ...